# Notepad++: Positional Insert (automatic padding)

Tags: notepad++

Sometimes, it makes more sense to see text appear side by side and to be able to arbitrarily insert characters to the right of what's been written (without having to pad the ends of each lines with space characters until you're at the column position where you want to insert text).

[image: Example]

It'd be convenient to have a toggle-hotkey binding (Ctrl + Left-Click) that automatically pads spaces to the column position you've clicked and insert that padding for each subsequent lines (until you turn it off).

Is this a feature of notepad++ or some notepad++ plugin? Is this a feature of any other editor (if so, what is it called there)?

Comment: Have you tried "Clone to other view" feature?

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Left-click mouse + Select the block you want
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Left-click mouse + Select the first column where you want to put the block
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>